# JQuery bind dom element click event to member function

Tags: jquery, function, events, bind, anonymous

I have a class in javascript with a function:

```
function myClass()
{
    this.myInit = function()
    {
        myObj = this;
        var id-foo = 'myId';
        jQuery('#'+id-foo).bind('click', function() { myObj.foo(id-foo); } );
    }

    this.foo = function(id) { alert(id); }
}
```

I want just to bind a DOM element to an event (click, dragonstart etc.) and make it call a function of the current object (actually this). I've tried to call this.foo directly but that doesnt work, firebug tells me that foo is not a function. Is the parameter id-foo which I give to the anonymous function the problem?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
 var id-foo = 'myId';
```

This isn't a valid name for a variable.

Note also that your code won't work if you don't call the `myInit` function on an instance of `myClass`.

This, for example, wouldn't work :

```
var obj = new myClass();
var f = obj.myInit;
f();
```

while this one should work :

```
var obj = new myClass();
obj.myInit();
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/Sm9S4/)

Comment: I am sry, this was just the abstract example, the wrong variable is just a miss typing. so pls assume the variable has name id_foo, but the example is not working though!

Comment: If my edit isn't enough for you to fix the problem, can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem ?

Comment: yes, the myInit function is called on an instance of myClass. But when I click on the website on the element with id="myId" it says that function foo is not found

Comment: See edit : I added a demonstration of the working code. Maybe you'll see where your error was.

Comment: thx for the fiddle, I built one myself: http://jsfiddle.net/tfZFh/5/ Somewhere must be the difference

Comment: Use `jQuery('#' + id).bind('click',` and not `jQuery('#' + id).bind('onclick',`. The event is of type `click`.

Comment: Yes i have recognized that. It makes the difference in the fiddle, but not in my original code! I have to go through the code again. Thx

Comment: Ah I found the mistake myself. I had another onclick handler directly at the html element and not removed it yet. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

After following @dystroy's answer then I would suggest you to not confuse yourself with the `this` keyword. Follow this pattern

```
var myClass = function () {
    myInit: function()
    {
        myObj = this;
        var id_foo = 'myId';
        jQuery('#'+id_foo).bind('click', function() { myObj.foo(id_foo); } );
    }

    foo: function(id) { alert(id); }
}
```

Comment: that is not a legal way of declaring a "class" - you've mixed object literal syntax with functions.